High Reprojection Errors in MoveIt Hand-Eye Calibration with uFactory Lite 6 Arm — How Can I Improve Accuracy in a Confined Space?
I'm working on calibrating the hand-eye coordination of my uFactory Lite 6 robot arm using MoveIt's Hand-Eye Calibration tool, but I'm consistently getting high "reprojection errors" ranging from 3 to 6 cm, which is unacceptable for my application. The calculated calibrated pose after each additional data entry continues to move by a substantial amount from the pose before, without converging to an accurate pose after multiple data points (that's what I would have expected).
I am aware that my setup is quite unusual, but this is fixed, so the solution has to come from the software/method.
Setup Details:

Robot Arm: uFactory Lite 6

Calibration Targets: Charuco board (I've tried several different ones)

Camera Model: Realsense D435

Camera Position: The camera is mounted close to the robot base and only captures the last few joints of the arm with the calibration target attached to the end effector.

Environment: The robot is suspended in a moderately confined space, limiting the diversity of robot pose configurations I can achieve during calibration.


Issues Faced:
Despite multiple calibration attempts with different Charuco boards, the reprojection errors remain high.
The confined space restricts the range of motion and variety of poses, which I suspect might be affecting the calibration quality.
The camera's proximity to the robot base limits its field of view to only a portion of the robot arm.
Questions:

How can I improve the accuracy of the hand-eye calibration given the constraints of my setup?
Are there best practices for performing calibration in confined spaces with limited robot pose diversity?
Are there any other calibration tools besides moveit_calibration that would be better suited for such a setup?

Any advice or suggestions to improve the calibration results would be greatly appreciated. I'm aiming to achieve a much lower error margin suitable for precise operations.
Here you can see my camera/arm setup:

Here is a screenshot of my detection image for context:

Thank you in advance for your help!

Image links are broken
